# Windows 7 how to have mouse keys on, and retain use of numeric pad for numbers at same time

Tags: windows-7, mouse, keyboard-layout

Windows 7 how to have mouse keys on, and retain use of numeric pad for numbers at same time

Plus still be able to use numeric pad for numbers at same time?

I bought a separate usb numeric pad in hopes id be able to gear the mousekeys towards it..

Comment: What are mouse keys?

Comment: the function where u turn ur dialpad on ur keyboard into a cursor guide, aka mouse

Comment: MAYBE AutoHotKey will work here? You may be able, when in this mode, to map a key combination to replicate default values. EG, if in mouse keys on mode, the 8 equals "move mouse cursor up", you could hold ALT + 8 and it would send 8